# formatação de valores de um dicionario

Tags: python

```
tamanho = int(input())
agenda = {}
cont = 0
for c in range(tamanho):
    cont += 1
    nome = str(input()).strip().lower().capitalize()
    cidade = str(input()).lower().capitalize()
    estado = str(input()).upper()
    telefone = input()
    agenda[cont] = nome,cidade,estado,telefone

for v in agenda.values():
    print(f'{v[0]:10}{v[1]}{v[2]:10}{v[3]:10}')
```

Não sei fazer uma formatação mais coerente do que essa que fiz ,desses valores do dicionario, mais se existe um forma melhor para fazer isso, por gentiliza poderia mi dá umas ideias de como faz.

Exemplos de entrada:

```
4
Gael
São Luís
MA
97824-4673
Vitória
Manaus
AM
98084-8437
Alícia
Brasília
DF
99114-8269
Clara
Duque de Caxias
RJ
97906-7003
```

A saída que esperava era essa:

```
Gael                     São Luís(MA)                  97824-4673
Vitória                  Manaus(AM)                    98084-8437
Alícia                   Brasília(DF)                  99114-8269
Clara                    Duque de Caxias(RJ)           97906-7003
```

Comment: Você pode usar os métodos `rjust` e `ljust` Veja [aqui](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-ljust-rjust-center/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, se as chaves do dicionário são 1, 2, 3, etc, não há muita vantagem em usar um dicionário. Quando as chaves são números sequenciais, isso é um forte indício de que talvez o que você precise é de uma lista.

E para formatar, você pode usar as [opções de formatação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec), como já está fazendo. A diferença é que o telefone está alinhado à direita, então basta fazer `>tamanho`, assim:

```
tamanho = int(input())
agenda = []
for _ in range(tamanho):
    nome = input().strip().lower().capitalize()
    cidade = input().lower().capitalize()
    estado = input().upper()
    telefone = input()
    # insere a tupla na lista
    agenda.append((nome,cidade,estado,telefone))

for nome, cidade, estado, telefone in agenda:
    # junta cidade e estado (com o estado entre parênteses)
    cid_uf = f'{cidade}({estado})'
    # nome alinhado à esquerda com 20 posições
    # cidade e estado alinhado à esquerda com 20 posições
    # telefone alinhado à direita com 20 posições
    print(f'{nome:20}{cid_uf:20}{telefone:>20}')
```

Repare também que no `for` eu posso atribuir os valores da tupla diretamente em variáveis específicas, assim facilita na hora de manipulá-las.

E veja que para inserir a tupla na lista eu preciso de parênteses extras: `agenda.append((nome,cidade,estado,telefone))`.
Se eu fizer apenas `agenda.append(nome,cidade,estado,telefone)`, dará erro, porque assim estarei passando 4 argumentos para `append`. Com os parênteses extras, eu passo apenas 1 argumento, que é a tupla contendo as 4 informações.

Eu juntei a cidade e estado antes porque me parece que eles fazem parte da mesma coluna, então se juntá-los fica mais fácil para formatar depois.

E coloquei o tamanho igual a 20 porque o telefone já tem 10 caracteres, então se usar o tamanho igual a 10 não fará diferença na formatação. Mas aí você pode ajustar os valores para o que precisar.

Outro detalhe é que [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) já retorna uma string, então fazer `str(input())` é redundante e desnecessário.

A saída é:

```
Gael                São luís(MA)                  97824-4673
Vitória             Manaus(AM)                    98084-8437
Alícia              Brasília(DF)                  99114-8269
Clara               Duque de caxias(RJ)           97906-7003
```